# /search is appended to all my URLS

Tags: 7, search, uri

Does anyone know why Drupal 7 takes all of my URL aliases, and adds a /search at the end of each URL?

So it's creating duplicate content, duplicate title tags, etc, delivering the same content and 2 different URLS.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Try it on another computer and browser...same thing?

Comment: This is not the behavior you get by a plain Drupal installation; clearly there is a module that is doing that. Do you notice any redirect?

Comment: Are these URLs something specific, like only node urls, taxonomy urls, user urls? What about URLs, like admin, urls generated by some modules? What about homepage url?